# rewrite url in .htacess not working in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working using php and apache server, I want to  rewrite `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/gift.php`   to `fdp/gift` and `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/another.php` `fdp/another` 
exactly I want do this

rewrite `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/*.php` to `fpd/*`

rewrite mode  is enable and I try below code in `.htacess` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^fpd/?$  sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/$1.php
```

but  nothing happened,what is the correct way to achieve this ?

Appreciate any help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first group and capture part of URI on LHS of URI pattern before you can use `$1`, `$2` etc on RHS.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^fpd/([^/]+)/?$ /sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/$1.php [L,NC]
```

**PS:** In your question you have used both `fpd` and `fdp`. Not sure which one is right.

Comment: I try this but nothing happened 
` RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^fpd/([^/]+)/?$ /sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/$1.php [L,NC]`

Comment: I test your rule in http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ 
with this url `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/tshirt.php` but told there is not match

Comment: 1. Never test on that site as it is not reliable. 2. You need to enter your URI as `http://example.com/fpd/tshirt.php` which will be internally forwarded to `http://example.com/sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/tshirt.php`

Comment: after rewrite I have a problem, please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763316/image-and-css-and-js-not-load-after-using-url-rewrite

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`RewriteRule ^fpd/(.+)$  sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/$1.php`

You might want to exclude the `/` symbol, if so, then replace the `.+` with `[^/]+`.

You have to enclose the part that you want placed into a variable with `()`, and each enclosed part will be put into $1, $2, $3 and so on.

Also, here is a nice tool to test your rewrite rules:

http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: I try  in tester you suggest ,  with url `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/tshirt.php` in return no match,

Comment: @zhilevan well it should't return anything. Type `fpd/tshirt` in the tester and you'll see it rewriten to `sites/all/themes/chap2014/fpd/tshirt.php`. That is what's going to be in yout URL after the domain after all