# how can I load image and css and js not load after using url rewrite with dynamic php solution

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, path

after I rewrite url with `RewriteRule ^fpd/([^/]+)/?$ /sites/all/themes/chapboo_2014/fpd/$1.php [L,NC]` , the css , js, and images not loaded in page.
I know It because  url rewriting.

I `echo getcwd();`  and it  return me `public_html/sites/all/themes/chapboo_2014/fpd` but nothing loaded correctly,how can I resolve this problem?
my pages is has several files and images, maybe 300 images, I prefer good solution till I change and use  absolute path in files path.
**appreciate any help**

example of my path

```
 <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/plugins.min.css" />
    <img src="images/designs/retro_1.png" title="Retro One" data-parameters='{"x": 210, "y": 200, "colors": "#000000", "removable": true, "draggable": true, "rotatable": true, "resizable": true, "scale": 0.25, "price": 7, "boundingBox": "Base", "autoCenter": true}' />
                        <img src="images/designs/retro_2.png" title="Retro Two" data-parameters='{"x": 193, "y": 180, "colors": "#ffffff", "removable": true, "draggable": true, "rotatable": true, "resizable": true, "scale": 0.46, "boundingBox": "Base", "autoCenter": true}' />
                        <img src="images/designs/retro_3.png" title="Retro Three" data-parameters='{"x": 240, "y": 200, "colors": "#000000", "removable": true, "draggable": true, "rotatable": true, "resizable": true, "scale": 0.25, "price": 8, "boundingBox": "Base", "autoCenter": true}' />
```

I see this solution [how can I load image and css and js not load after using url rewrite with dynamic php solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763316/image-and-css-and-js-not-load-after-using-url-rewrite) but it answered by static answer, I have plenty file in my pages ,maybe it need php solution, change direcotry or something

Comment: What is example of a correct path of css or image file?

Comment: `images/designs/retro_2.png` is just a relative path of image. I needed to know to **full** and correct path where image will be found.

Comment: @anubhava the full path is mysite.com/sites/all/themes/chapboo_2014/fpd/images/designs/file.png

Comment: ok try placing `<base href="http://yoursite.com/sites/all/themes/chapboo_2014/fpd/">` in the `<head>` section of your page.